# What's the difference between → and ∧ in this context?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

What I already knew:
Normally, I understand that "→" means implication, whereas "∧" means conjunction.
The answer to this question is:

c. P(-5)∧P(-3)∧P(-1)∧P(3)∧P(5)

d. P(1)∨P(3)∨P(5)

It seems that "∀" and "∃" tells me whether to use "∧" or "∨", but I don't understand what the ∧ and → do?

If you find my question to be too confusing, could you solve this:
What happens if I replaced → with ∧ in question C, or ∧ with → in question D?

I have to ask this question again despite it already exists because the original question asks about translation, but I still can't understand enough to see the difference in this context. I'm still learning.

[image]

Comment: In a finite domain $\forall$ acts as a conjunction and $\exists$ as a dicjunction. Thus, d) amounts to $[(-5 \ge 0) \land P(-5)] \lor \ldots \lor [(3 \ge 0) \land P(3)]$ and similar for c) $[(-5 \ne 1) \to P(-5)] \land \ldots \land [(3 \ne 1) \to P(3)]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic difference between $\to$ and $\land$ is that while $(−5≠1)→P(−5)$ is True because the antecedent is False, we have that $(−5≠1) \land P(−5)$ is False because at least the first conjunct is False.

Regarding the problem above, we have that in a finite domain $∀$ acts as a *conjunction* while $∃$ as a *disjunction*. Thus, d) amounts to $[(−5≥0) ∧ P(−5)] \lor \ldots \lor [(3≥0) ∧ P(3)]$ and c) to $[(−5 \ne 1) → P(−5)] ∧ \ldots ∧ [(3 \ne 1) → P(3)]$.

See also [Quantifier (logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) and [Bounded quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier): $(∃n<t) \varphi$ means $∃n(n<t ∧ \varphi)$ while $(∀n<t) \varphi$ means $∀n(n<t → \varphi)$.